# Facing trouble in understanding windows client server architecture for processes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, window, visual-c++

I have written a simple program that goes like this ..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    while(1)
        printf("......%d...\n",i++);
    return 0;

}
```

When this process will run under windows, it will act like a client and the server will be Csrss.exe. Now my question is that when this client will try to print something it will send a request to the server, and the further process about printing is done by the server(Csrss.exe).But what would happen with the client? the client process will continue executing without bothering about whether the value actually get printed or not? or the server will block the client until it get some notification from system space ??

If you are going with the second solution then please also explain that in MSDN it is written that after using CreateProcess() we should use WaitForInputIdle() API to make sure that the object is actually created in the system space. So what I can get from this statement is that server will not block the client after making a request ..

and if you are going with the first solution then the output of the program is correct, i mean not a single value of i got missed ??

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your process' standard output is a pipe to csrss.exe. `printf` writes to that pipe. It would block at least until the data is stored in some system buffer. Whether it blocks all the way until the server reads the text from the pipe and renders it on the screen, I'm not sure, and I don't quite see why it would matter.

`WaitForInputIdle` is only significant for windowed applications, not for console ones. It waits until the target process calls `GetMessage` or similar for the first time. Console processes don't typically do that. From the documentation: "If this process is a console application ..., `WaitForInputIdle` returns immediately."

I don't understand your concern about "missed values".

Comment: actually what i thought is that the print statement would make a request to the server, and server would just take the request and client will continue to execute, and since i kept printf in while loop so it will generate requests from client very rapidly, and server won't be able to fulfill all of them, so few prints won't get a chance to render, and the output would look like this 1 2 5 7 8 ..   but the actual o/p is 1 2 3 4 5 ...

Comment: How can I judge that my newly created process will be handled by which subsystem? Like you just said that this is a console application? How did you decide that ?

Comment: Well, you call `printf` and, apparently, actually see its output in a console window; which means that your process gets associated with one, making it a console process. You specify the subsystem at build time, using [this setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx).

Comment: ok, i am going to ask a new question to make my question more clear.